# How to fix: value may contain references; add `'static` bound to `T`

Tags: rust, object-lifetime

I managed yet again to run into a lifetime issue that I seem to be unable to solve on my own.

I have this trait

```
pub trait MiddlewareHandler: Clone {
    fn invoke (&self, req: &Request, res: &mut Response) -> bool {
        true
    }

    // we need this because otherwise clone() would be ambiguous
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<MiddlewareHandler> { 
        box self.clone() as Box<MiddlewareHandler> 
    }
}

impl MiddlewareHandler for fn (req: &Request, res: &mut Response) -> bool {
    fn invoke(&self, req: &Request, res: &mut Response) -> bool{
        (*self).invoke(req, res)
    }
}

impl Clone for Box<MiddlewareHandler> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<MiddlewareHandler> { 
        self.clone_box() 
    }
}
```

That I implement for `fn (req: &Request, res: &mut Response) -> bool` in order to be able to use accept lightweight functions and more heavy weight `MiddlewareHandler` implementors at the same time.

I store them as `Vec<Box<MiddlewareHandler>>`

```
pub struct Middleware {
    handlers: Vec<Box<MiddlewareHandler>>
}
```

Now, the problem is, the compiler is yelling at me right here:

```
    pub fn add<T: MiddlewareHandler> (&mut self, handler: T) {
        self.handlers.push(box handler);
    }
```

It says:

```
error: value may contain references; add `'static` bound to `T`
       self.handlers.push(box handler);
```

The implementation should be pretty similar to the one used here:

https://github.com/iron/iron/blob/master/src/chain/stackchain.rs#L67

However, I seem to be unable to see the difference :-/

If anyone would like to give me a hand, I pushed the code to github into the `static` branch:

https://github.com/floor-org/floor/tree/static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, in order to safely create a boxed trait object, the original object cannot have any lifetime parameters (besides `static`), or the object itself also needs to respect that lifetime, which isn't possible in general. To fix it:

```
pub fn add<T: MiddlewareHandler + 'static> (&mut self, handler: T) {
    self.handlers.push(box handler);
}
```

Reads a bit weird, but it's saying "`T` needs to implement `MiddlewareHandler` and it cannot contain any references that do not have the `static` lifetime". This only works for `static`.

Comment: I think I added `' static` to pretty much every place in this snippet but I obviously missed to try `+ 'static`there ;-) But one thing I don't understand is why it is not needed there: https://github.com/iron/iron/blob/master/src/chain/stackchain.rs#L67

How is their implementation different in that regard?

Comment: Because the trait inherits from `Send`, and `Send` implies `'static`

Comment: Damn it! I looked at the documentation for `Send` but it didn't ring a bell because I don't spawn any tasks here, so it seemed to be superfluous. 

Maybe you can answer two extra questions:

`pub trait MiddlewareHandler: Clone + Send` works but it feels weird to "abuse" `Send` for that. Why can't I use `pub trait MiddlewareHandler: Clone + 'static` then?

You said `Send` implies `'static` but I looked at the source of http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/kinds/trait.Send.html and can't find any  hints about that. I would expect to see a `'static` there somewhere.

Comment: The kinds are a bit weird, they are language builtins right now (though [there is an RFC to change that](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/127)). I would *expect* `Clone + 'static` to work, I'm sad that it doesn't.

Comment: Ok,  then.  Would it be correct to derive from `send` if you really just want to make your type static atm? I want to write  idiomatic Rust and deriving from `send` seems unnecessary given its description. Would you do the same here with the current design of Rust?

Answer (score 1):

A trait object erases the type of the internal data, meaning it is not known just by looking at the `Box<Trait>` trait object. In particular, any lifetimes of the data is erased too, so the compiler cannot tell if/when a trait object contains references to invalid data (i.e. lifetime of some reference has expired), hence Rust currently enforces that any data in a owned trait object must never "expire". That is, there are no references in it (well, to be precise that any references are valid forever, i.e. `'static`).

This expressed via the built-in "trait" `'static`:

```
pub fn add<T: 'static + MiddlewareHandler>(...
```

(This may change in future, with owned trait objects able to be bounded by real lifetimes, and so storing non-`'static` references would be safe.)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for that. I still wonder why this works for them:

https://github.com/iron/iron/blob/master/src/chain/stackchain.rs#L67

I don't see how their code is different from mine. Also if I change the code like that I run into the next error `instantiating a type parameter with an incompatible type T, which does not fulfill 'static`

So, this seems to be indicating that I have an error somewhere else maybe? :-S