# How can I downcast from Box<Any> to a trait object type?

Tags: rust, downcast

```
pub struct WidgetWrap {
    // ...
    widget: RefCell<Box<Any>>,
}
```

At some point I want to cast `Box<Any>` to `Box<WidgetTrait>`

```
let mut cell = widget.borrow_mut();
let w = cell.downcast_mut::<Box<WidgetTrait>>();
```

This gives me an error of this kind:

```
error: instantiating a type parameter with an incompatible type
`Box<WidgetTrait>`, which does not fulfill `'static` [E0144]
```

What does this really mean?

I've looked at [How to fix: value may contain references; add `'static` bound to `T`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375771/how-to-fix-value-may-contain-references-add-static-bound-to-t) and did try adding `+ 'static` everywhere.

```
pub struct WidgetWrap {
    // ...
    widget: RefCell<Box<Any + 'static>>,
}
let mut cell = widget.borrow_mut();
let w = cell.downcast_mut::<Box<WidgetTrait + 'static>>();
```

It fixes the compile errors, but fails when I try to unwrap the downcasted box as shown above. And yes, the content of the box is an object that implements `WidgetTrait`.

Obviously, I am coding in Rust at a level that I don't quite understand, but maybe someone can help me get a better grip on the concepts involved in the above task.

Comment: Why use `Box<Any>` at all if it's supposed to be a `Box<WidgetTrait>`?

Comment: The `Box<Any>` are a wide variety of values. They all have the `WidgetTrait`, but I also need to occasionally cast them to their specific instances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(I shall ignore the `'static` part as it’s comparatively irrelevant for the parts I’m explaining.)

`Box<Trait>` for a given trait `Trait` is stored as two pieces of data: a pointer to the actual data in memory and a pointer to the vtable for its type’s implementation of `Trait`.

From that, you may see that you can only have one level of traityness—if you have a `Box<WidgetTrait>` and you box it again as `Box<Any>`, you would only be able to get it out as a `Box<WidgetTrait>` object. Similarly, if you take a type `Widget` that implements `WidgetTrait` and box it in a `Box<Any>`, you can only get it out as a `Widget` object, not as a `Box<WidgetTrait>` object.

Such is the nature of the type IDs being used internally: unlike in a dynamic or VM-based language, the type system is purely a compile-time construct; *there is no such thing as the type system at runtime*.

The solution, if you really *need* a solution along these lines (you probably don’t; sticking with just a `Box<WidgetTrait>` is probably the best way) is to have a trait which also implements what `Any` does. This is not the simplest thing at present, but can be done. [Teepee’s `Header` trait](https://github.com/teepee/teepee/blob/17d69d7f3ba0c9be51538148d6d7e47d7f474486/src/httpcommon/headers/mod.rs) is an example of how this can work; a `Box<Header>` object will have the header-transforming methods as well as `Any`’s `.downcast_ref()` and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

The original code works as-is in at least Rust 1.25; presumably there was a bug or limitation in the compiler that has since been fixed:

```rust
use std::{any::Any, cell::RefCell};

trait WidgetTrait {}

fn example(widget: RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>) {
    let mut cell = widget.borrow_mut();
    let _w = cell.downcast_mut::<Box<dyn WidgetTrait>>();
}
```

As pointed out by [trentcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246443/how-can-i-downcast-from-boxany-to-a-trait-object-type#comment95842927_50280285), that doesn't mean that this *does what you want*:

> This compiles, I admit, but it cannot succeed when the content of the box is an object that implements `WidgetTrait,` because it downcasts specifically to `Box<WidgetTrait (+ 'static)>`. You'd have to create a `Box<Box<WidgetTrait + 'static>>` for it to work. (Put another way, the type parameter of `downcast_mut` is the unboxed type `T`, not `Box<T>`.)

```rust
use std::{any::Any, cell::RefCell};

trait WidgetTrait {
    fn demo(&mut self);
}

fn example(widget: RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>) {
    let mut cell = widget.borrow_mut();
    match cell.downcast_mut::<Box<dyn WidgetTrait>>() {
        Some(w) => w.demo(),
        None => println!("Not here!"),
    }
}

struct Alpha(u8);
impl WidgetTrait for Alpha {
    fn demo(&mut self) {
        self.0 += 1;
        dbg!(self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(Alpha(0));
    let r = RefCell::new(b);
    example(r);
}
```

```
Not here!
```

Boxing it twice:

```rust
fn main() {
    let b: Box<dyn WidgetTrait> = Box::new(Alpha(0));
    let b2: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(b);
    let r = RefCell::new(b2);
    example(r);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:19] self.0 = 1
```

See also:

- [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423)

Comment: This compiles, I admit, but it cannot succeed when the content of the box is *an object that implements `WidgetTrait`*, because it downcasts specifically to `Box<WidgetTrait (+ 'static)>`. You'd have to create a `Box<Box<WidgetTrait + 'static>>` for it to work. (Put another way, the type parameter of `downcast_mut` is the unboxed type `T`, not `Box<T>`.)