# Is it possible to cast a trait to the implementing struct?

Tags: rust

I have a binding to a trait, and I want to cast it to the implementing struct so that I can call a method implemented on that struct.  Is this possible?  Below is code that illustrates what I'd like to do:

```
struct Struct {
    num: u8
}

trait Trait {
    fn trait_fn(&self) -> u8;
}

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn trait_fn(&self) -> u8 {
        self.num + 1
    }
}

impl Struct {
    fn struct_fn(&self) -> u8 {
        self.num - 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t: Box<Trait> = Box::new(Struct { num: 5 });
    let t_result = t.trait_fn();
    let s_result = (*t as Struct).struct_fn(); // How can I do something like this?
    println!("Trait Result: {}, Struct Result: {}", t_result, s_result);
}
```

Comment: This is called "downcasting" and isn't really available. This will be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27892375/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/25246443/155423.

Comment: BTW: In some situations it is helful to use an enum rather than a trait. This allows you to use match instead of downcasting. 

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/enums.html