# Dynamic cast (run-time type inference) in Rust

Tags: polymorphism, rust, type-inference, dynamic-cast

Is this type of polymorphism possible in Rust, or is it planned?

I.e.

```
trait R { ... }
struct S { ... }
impl R for S { ... }

let r: Box<R> = Box::new(S { ... });
let s: Box<S> = dynamic_cast<Box<S>>(r).expect("r is a boxed S");
```

I am aware that `std::mem::transmute` provides an unsafe way of doing this, but don't see any explicit support for dynamic_cast (which, I guess, is fine).

Comment: This is referred to as *downcasting*. You should mark this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27892375/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/25246443/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423 or (insert more search results here).

Comment: Thanks. But up, down... you're clearly talking about tree roots not branches ;-)