# Is it possible to pattern match in Rust with multiple types?

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

It seems as though you can't. If not, is there any planned support to add it or run-time type information (RTTI)?

```
struct Bus;
struct Car;
struct Person;

fn main() {
    let x = Bus;
    //or more realistically, let x = function_with_multiple_return_types();

    match x {
        Car => {
            // ...
        }
        Bus => {
            // this gets executed
        }
        Person => {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This example is trivial. In real life, it would only be useful if `x` could be multiple types. e.g. `let x = function_with_multiple_return_types();`.

Comment: Idk Rust, but I would expect that each clause of the match would need to be of the same type. Try making them all part of the same superclass / interface

Comment: The closest thing you can get may be a tagged union such as the example [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/enums.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No one can say with 100% accuracy that a feature will or won't **ever** be implemented, but I can say with 100% belief that this will never be implemented.

Why is that? Because there's zero benefit to the proposed syntax. Rust is a *statically-typed* language. That means that the compiler *knows* what the type of a variable is. There's no way that any branch besides `Bus` would ever be executed. There's no way that a variable can have more than one type! Why would the language change to allow you to add code that could never be used? That wouldn't be very useful.

A match statement, and pattern matching in general, is really only useful when there are multiple possible variants of something. That's why Rust has `enum`s; to allow a fixed set of dynamic choices (a.k.a. made at runtime).

If you need an open set of dynamic decisions, that's what traits (and maybe specialization) are for. There's even a trait that allows for [any concrete type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html).

---

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538554/is-it-possible-to-pattern-match-in-rust-with-multiple-types#comment68346311_40538795), you can use *trait object downcasting* which is provided by [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html), but there's no ability to use `match`.

See also:

- [Can I do type introspection with trait objects and then downcast it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27892375/155423)

Comment: My question was inspired from a Racket interpreter I wrote where Match could branch on different types. Lisp is of course dynamically typed, though, so it makes sense in Rust this is not typically useful. I feel there there could be niche cases where having a function return types dynamically could be useful (though not idomatic) - std::any seems to mostly cover this use case though. Thanks!

Comment: Lisp being dynamically typed is where my initial confusion came from.

Comment: *return types dynamically* — but even then you want to *do* something with those returned types. That means there is a set of methods that you want to be able to call; that's what a trait implies. It can be returned as a trait object.

Comment: @Shepmaster What if the match goes over a reference, a trait implementation, trying to downcast it (`let x: &Display = ...; match x {&String => ...}`), and happens some place where the compiler doesn't know the exact type? Wouldn't that be useful?

Comment: @ArtemGr it does know the exact type — `&Display` ;-) It sounds like you are asking about *trait object downcasting* (see [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25246443/155423), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27892375/155423)), which is provided by `Any`. There's no ability to `match` though, as `match` would need to statically know all the possibilities, as I understand it.

Comment: @Shepmaster I knows about anys and it's not very ergonomics, don't you sees? And wouldn't blanks (`_`) save the match from needsing to know too much?

Comment: There's even a room to implement something like the Scala typeful Duck Typing, methinks. Wich is a different route from downcasting but interesting nevertheless.

Comment: The issue is the compiler may know the exact type, but the user does not know it / has no way to express it when using a macro. As a macro can return any type and macro's can't do any sort of type-checking, the only way to check would be with conditions that are being resolved by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`std::any::Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) and Andrew Johnson's link. I think you will be able to do something close to what you wanted to do using `Any`. `fn get_type_id(&self) -> TypeId` is only in the nightly builds though, so if you have the stable version of Rust you may be unable to use it yet.

[This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aany%3A%3AAny%3B%0A%0Afn%20is_string(s%3A%20%26(Any%20%2B%20Send))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20s.is%3A%3A%3CString%3E()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22It%27s%20a%20string!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Not%20a%20string...%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20is_string(%260)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20is_string(%26%22cookie%20monster%22.to_string())%3B%0A%7D) example is close to what you want, just with `if let` instead of `match`.

I wrote three examples to demonstrate how you might accomplish this, Although none are usable with `match` sadly... They can be found be found and run [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8ab4c0a8b56de5e45d37b7cd9e0af57c&version=undefined&mode=undefined). The following is my favorite way of doing it:

```
fn run_example_one() {
    let unknown_type = gen_rand_any();

    if let Some(string) = unknown_type.downcast_ref::<String>() {
       println!("It's a string!");
    } else if let Some(my_struct) = unknown_type.downcast_ref::<MyStruct>() {
        println!("my struct! name = {:?}", my_struct.my_name);
    } else if let Some(int) = unknown_type.downcast_ref::<i32>() {
       println!("something singed 32 bit int.");
   }
}
```

Comment: See [match_cast](https://crates.io/crates/match_cast). This is a minimal crate which implements match through different types.