# How to get mutable struct from boxed trait

Tags: rust

I'd like to modify data in a struct based on a trait that is boxed. The following code prints the value but gives me "cannot mutably borrow immutable field" when I try to change it or "cannot borrow as mutable" when calling its function.

My plan is to have a vector of `Ai` each containing the `AiData` derived struct and then iterate over them, set some data in it and call the `tick()` function.

```
use std::any::Any;

pub trait AiData {
    fn tick(&mut self);
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any;
}

pub struct Ai {
    pub ai_data: Box<AiData>,
}

impl Ai {
    pub fn new(ai_data: Box<AiData>) -> Ai {
        Ai { ai_data: ai_data }
    }
}

pub struct TestAi {
    pub index: u8,
}

impl TestAi {
    pub fn new() -> TestAi {
        TestAi { index: 1 }
    }
}

impl AiData for TestAi {
    fn tick(&mut self) {
        println!("tick");
    }

    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ai_data: TestAi = TestAi::new();
    let ai: Ai = Ai::new(Box::new(ai_data));

    let b: &TestAi = match ai.ai_data.as_any().downcast_ref::<TestAi>() {
        Some(b) => b,
        None => panic!("&a isn't a B!"),
    };
    println!("{:?}", b.index);

    b.tick();
    b.index = 2;
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*b` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:48:5
   |
48 |     b.tick();
   |     ^ cannot borrow as mutable

error[E0594]: cannot assign to immutable field `b.index`
  --> src/main.rs:49:5
   |
49 |     b.index = 2;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow immutable field
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that you can get a mutable reference from this immutable variable? Have you already read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), the free official book which explains Rust concepts like mutability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get mutable struct from boxed trait

You cannot get a struct from the boxed trait object. You can get a reference to the struct, however.

As [explained in *The Rust Programming Language*'s chapter on variables and mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html), mutability is a property of the binding. Additionally, as described in [the chapter on references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html), a mutable reference (`&mut T`) is distinct from an immutable reference (`&T`). Based on these two points, you cannot get a mutable reference from an immutable variable<sup>1</sup>.

The code has:

- An immutable variable
- An immutable reference to that variable
- Calls `Any::downcast_ref`, which returns an immutable reference

When you fix all of those, the code works:

```
use std::any::Any;

pub trait AiData {
    fn tick(&mut self);
    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Any;
}

pub struct Ai {
    pub ai_data: Box<AiData>,
}

impl Ai {
    pub fn new(ai_data: Box<AiData>) -> Ai {
        Ai { ai_data }
    }
}

pub struct TestAi {
    pub index: u8,
}

impl TestAi {
    pub fn new() -> TestAi {
        TestAi { index: 1 }
    }
}

impl AiData for TestAi {
    fn tick(&mut self) {
        println!("tick");
    }

    fn as_any_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ai_data = TestAi::new();
    let mut ai = Ai::new(Box::new(ai_data));

    let b = ai.ai_data
        .as_any_mut()
        .downcast_mut::<TestAi>()
        .expect("&a isn't a B!");
    println!("{:?}", b.index);

    b.tick();
    b.index = 2;
}
```

<sup>1</sup> You can read about [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) which actually does allow you to get a mutable reference from an immutable variable, at the expense of introducing runtime checks to prevent aliasing.

See also:

- [Rust: downcasting and Box<Any>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25246443/155423)
- [How to get a struct reference from a boxed trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. The trick is I did try to mut trait the same way you did and fixed impl accordingly and had downcast_mut, but it didn't work for me becuse I missed 'let b: &mut TestAi ...'. I had  'let mut b: &TestAi' instead.

Comment: @Skemp there's no reason to have an explicit type there to start with. Idiomatic Rust eschews them.

Comment: I'm just used to do it like this from other languages and it's also more readable to me.

Comment: @Skemp How `let ai_data: TestAi = TestAi::new();` is more readable? That's like, for example, writing `FooBar f = new FooBar();` in C#. You duplicate information without any benefit. Furthermore, if you want to replicate some irrelevant foreign idioms in Rust (same for any language), you are on the wrong path.

Comment: @Boiethios In this case readability is not improved. But in this `let b: &TestAi = match ai.ai_data.as_any().downcast_ref::<TestAi>() {
        Some(b) => b,
        None => panic!("&a isn't a B!"),
    };` it is, at least for me. Also, I'm rust noob, but I'm trying to improve.