# How can I test an object's other-trait functions

Tags: rust

I have a `Template` struct implementing a `encoder` function that returns a reference to a `Box`ed `Encoder`.

I also have a `FixedEncoder` struct that implements `Encoder`

I can create the `Template` and get the `Encoder` out, but how do I test the functions of `FixedEncoder`? I'm only looking to get `FixedEncoder` for testing purposes, so "unsafe" solutions are fine (though safe ones are preferred)

In my following example I get the error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `length` found for type `&std::boxed::Box<(dyn Encoder + 'static)>` in the current scope
```

Example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=367f28a96807ce8b513714cfa7f1cd37)):

```
pub struct Template {
    encoder: Box<Encoder>
}

impl Template {
    fn new(encoder: Box<Encoder>) -> Template {
        Template { encoder }
    }

    fn encoder(&self) -> &Box<Encoder> {
        &self.encoder
    }
}

pub trait Encoder {
    fn isEncoder(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

pub struct FixedEncoder {
    length: usize
}

impl FixedEncoder {
    pub fn new(length: usize) -> FixedEncoder {
        FixedEncoder { length }
    }

    pub fn length(&self) -> usize {
        self.length
    }
}

impl Encoder for FixedEncoder {}

fn main() {
    let fixed_encoder = FixedEncoder::new(1);
    let template = Template::new(Box::new(fixed_encoder));
    assert_eq!(template.encoder().isEncoder(), true); // works
    assert_eq!(&template.encoder().length(), 1); // error[E0599]: no method named `length` found for type `&std::boxed::Box<(dyn Encoder + 'static)>` in the current scope
}
```

Comment: It isn't possible to "cast" one trait object into another. Probably a more idiomatic approach would be to use an `enum` of the possible encoders, rather than traits.

Comment: For example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=a8193cbc1a72d00bf552b657a89142de

Comment: @PeterHall thanks! I'll try integrating and see if it works out. Very much appreciated

Comment: This answer may help to explain why you can't cast between traits - even if you know the type implements them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247480/493729

Comment: @PeterHall thanks for the link. I was aware of the inability to cast between traits and *sorta* understand why (that link certainly helps). I was looking for a workaround an I think the enum solution you provided should work (integrating now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using `Any`.

1. Add an `as_any` declaration to `Encoder`
2. Add an `as_any` function to `FixedEncoder`
3. Use `.as_any().downcast_ref().unwrap()` on the retreived `Encoder`

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=29c5a825aea64446c50bbf87264bc2ce)

```
use std::any::Any;

pub struct Template {
    encoder: Box<Encoder>
}

impl Template {
    fn new(encoder: Box<Encoder>) -> Template{
        Template {
            encoder
        }
    }
    fn encoder(&self) -> &Box<Encoder> {
        &self.encoder
    }
}

pub trait Encoder {
    fn isEncoder(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

pub struct FixedEncoder {
    length: usize
}
impl FixedEncoder {
    pub fn new(length: usize) -> FixedEncoder {
        FixedEncoder { length }
    }
    pub fn length(&self) -> usize {
        self.length
    }
}



impl Encoder for FixedEncoder {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let fixed_encoder = FixedEncoder::new(1);
    let template = Template::new(Box::new(fixed_encoder));
    assert_eq!(template.encoder().isEncoder(), true); // works

    let fixed_encoder_from_template : &FixedEncoder = &template.encoder().as_any().downcast_ref().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&fixed_encoder_from_template.length, &(1 as usize));
}
```