# How to offer an API that stores values of different types and can return them with the original type restored?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to offer a safe API like below `FooManager`. It should be able to store arbitrary user-defined values that implement a trait `Foo`. It should also be able to hand them back later - not as trait object (`Box<dyn Foo>`) but as the original type (`Box<T>` where `T: Foo`). At least conceptually it should be possible to offer this as a safe API, by using generic handles (`Handle<T>`), see below.

Additional criteria:

- The solution should work in stable Rust (internal usage of `unsafe` blocks is perfectly okay though).
- I don't want to modify the trait `Foo`, as e.g. suggested in [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object). It should work without adding a method `as_any()`. Reasoning: `Foo` shouldn't have any knowledge about the fact that it might be stored in containers and be restored to the actual type.

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct Handle<T> {
    // ...
}

struct FooManager {
    // ...
}

impl FooManager {
    // A real-world API would complain if the value is already stored.
    pub fn keep_foo<T: Foo>(&mut self, foo: Box<T>) -> Handle<T> {
        // ...
    }
    
    // In a real-world API this would return an `Option`.
    pub fn return_foo<T: Foo>(&mut self, handle: Handle<T>) -> Box<T> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I came up with [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed10d40758530feedd230ba3b817deea) (Rust Playground) but not sure if there's a better way or if it's safe even. What do you think of that approach?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423); [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632968); [Can I do type introspection with trait objects and then downcast it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27892375); [How can I downcast from Box<Any> to a trait object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25246443). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object)

Comment: Maybe you can build `HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Foo>>`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I've added some criteria which should distinguish this question from the - I think - more general question discussed in your first link. Could you please have a look at the Rust playground example and maybe point out if something is wrong with it?

Comment: @rodrigo A HashMap sounds good and is what I used for looking up the stored values again. But how's the `TypeId` as key going to help exactly?

Comment: @helgoboss: Something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2429ccab3b7c8bb80990a49cbf0278e9), maybe.

Comment: @rodrigo Thank you. It goes to the right direction. Two things though: 1. It uses `as_any()`, which I don't want (my main issue with that solution). 2. `return_foo()` shouldn't do a look-up by type, but by whatever handle was returned from `keep_foo()`. It should be possible to keep multiple values of the same type. (That's not a problem though ... I can figure out how to adjust your solution.)