# Cast Rc<Any> to Rc<Trait>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a map, where a key is a `TypeId` of a trait and a value is a struct that implements it.

```
impls: HashMap<TypeId, Rc<dyn Any>>
```

To put a new object to the map, I use the next code:

```
let type_id = TypeId::of::<dyn Trait>();
let obj_ref: Rc<dyn Any> = Rc::new(obj);

self.impls.insert(type_id, Rc::clone(&obj_ref));
```

But when I try to get this object from the map, I need to cast it back.

```
let any_comp_ref = self.impls
    .get(&TypeId::of::<dyn Trait>())
    .expect(&format!("Object for type: {} is not found", type_name::<dyn Trait>()));

let result: &dyn Trait = // ???
```

I've tried to use `Rc::downcast`. But it's implemented only for `Sized` types.

Comment: If you are willing to go unsafe, you could save them as `std::raw::TraitObject` values or an equivalent non-nightly type. Highly unsafe and tricky to do right, but possible.

Comment: I actually think this is an oversight in the standard library. Maybe it's worth opening an issue? I think that `Any::is`, as well as all of the `downcast_*` methods in the standard library, should probably accept unsized types.

Comment: @rodrigo `std::raw::TraitObject` does not have the same layout as an `Rc<dyn Trait>`, since it also has a pointer to the ref counts.

Comment: @Coder-256 It's not an oversight, it's a logical consequence of the lack of RTTI in Rust. `dyn Any` doesn't retain enough information about the concrete type to "know" whether it implements any arbitrary trait, so such a method would have to materialize a vtable-pointer out of thin air.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I downcast from Box<Any> to a trait object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246443/how-can-i-downcast-from-boxany-to-a-trait-object-type) Relevant excerpt: "you can only have one level of traityness[...] if you take a type `Widget` that implements `WidgetTrait` and box it in a `Box<Any>`, you can only get it out as a `Widget` object, not as a `Box<WidgetTrait>` object."

Comment: If that's not it, perhaps you can solve your problem by [double-boxing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e02151fa81b62cda93230b5514587a82)?

Comment: @trentcl I am aware; `dyn Any` stores information for exactly one type (such as a trait, struct, enum, etc.). My only point was that I don't see why the implicit `Sized` bound is necessary for so many of those methods, and at least `Any::type_id` already doesn't require `Sized`.

Comment: @Coder-256  `downcast_ref` does need `Sized` though, because there's no way to go from (data ptr + `Any`-vtable ptr) to (data ptr + arbitrary metadata) because `Any` vtables don't retain any of that metadata that would be needed to downcast to an arbitrary trait object or slice type. (Not to mention that you can't cast `&dyn Trait` to `&dyn Any` in the first place; see [Why can't `&(?Sized + Trait)` be cast to `&dyn Trait`?](/q/57398118/3650362))

Comment: @trentcl Ok I see. Still, this seems like a compiler limitation, unless there is a possible blowup in pointer width? (I can’t seem to think of a situation where that would happen). In other words why can’t there be 3-pointer fat pointers?

Comment: @Coder-256 Well, if you do make an x3 "obese pointer", it can't be `Box<dyn Any>`, which is only two pointers. Let's call it `Box<dyn (Any + ...)>` to indicate we don't know what the second trait is. You *still* can't write `downcast_obese` from `Box<dyn (Any + ...)>` to `Box<dyn Trait>` because traits don't have a `TypeId` equivalent to check what *kind* of vtable it is. So the best you can do is `Box<dyn (Any + Trait)>`, where `Trait` is known, but that doesn't solve OP's problem because they want to have multiple trait object types in a collection.

Comment: Obese pointers (this is a term of art, BTW, not an original idea) are possible, they've been suggested before, they probably won't be added to the language, but even if they were they don't solve this problem. If you added a `TraitId` language mechanic as well, you *could*, but -- unlike `TypeId` -- `TraitId` is not zero-cost, because every vtable effectively has to have a runtime `TraitId` *whether or not* you ever try to `downcast_obese` it.

Comment: @trentcl That's a very good point. Honestly I don't think an extra `u64` for the `TraitId` in each vtable is very much of a cost, but that plus obese pointers plus multiple vtables for each trait certainly complicate things to the point where it's nowhere near trivial to implement, and it definitely seems like too much for something so niche.