# How to create a hashmap owing {Key: String, Value: function}

Tags: rust

I'm rust freshman

I want to use hashmap key to call funtion like below

```
let map = HashMap::from([("add", func_add), ("sub", func_sub)]);

if let Some(func) = map.get("add") {
    func();
}
else {}
```

functions in different keys may have different parameter quantities and types

Does this possible in rust?

If not, how can I call a function without fuction name(memory address or something)

Comment: If the functions have different parameters, how exactly do you plan on providing the parameters? It's unclear what you're trying to do right now. Please provide a [mre] with more details on your exact problem.

Comment: @Aplet123: This is what keys to do, key will clarify what  parameters should be provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> functions in different keys may have different parameter quantities and types Does this possible in rust?

No. Rust is *very* statically typed, it doesn't do "fuzzy".

> If not, how can I call a function without fuction name(memory address or something)

You can always do that, functions are first class objects in Rust.

You can even unify different functions *with the exact same signature* through the magic of function pointers (`fn()`) or trait objects (`dyn Fn()`):

```rust
fn main() {
    let m0: HashMap<&str, fn(i32, i32) -> i32> = [
        ("add", (|a, b| a + b) as _),
        ("sub", (|a, b| a - b) as _),
    ].into();
    
    dbg!(m0["sub"](1, 2));
    
    let m1: HashMap<&str, Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> i32>> = [
        ("add", Box::new(|a, b| a + b) as _),
        ("sub", Box::new(|a, b| a - b) as _),
    ].into();
    
    dbg!(m1["add"](1, 2));
}
```

However if you also need variable arities and types, then you need to reify that through additional layers of indirection e.g.

- double-type-erase through [double boxing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247480/8182118), that requires the least up-front work (just a bunch of casting) but the callsites become pretty gnarly:

  ```rust
  let m: HashMap<&str, Box<dyn Any>> = [
      ("neg", Box::new(Box::new(|a: i32| - a) as Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>) as _),
      ("add", Box::new(Box::new(|a, b| a + b) as Box<dyn Fn(i32, i32) -> i32>) as _),
  ].into();

  let f = &m["neg"];
  if let Some(f) = f.downcast_ref::<Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>>() {
      dbg!(f(5));
  }
  ```

  this can be simplified a bit through wrapper types, at the cost of more setup
- an exhaustive enums for all your combinations of parameters and types
- defining all your functions to have the same static interface (e.g. that all of them take an `Args` or `Vec<Arg>` which can be dynamically dispatched either internally or externally), possibly through a compatibility layer of macro(s), you might want to limit your input and output types and use something like `serde_json::Value` in that case

Other possibilities:

- use a struct rather than a hashmap, then each named slot can have a static type which makes things much easier
- use something like a *type map*, but that also requires wrapper type (per slot) in order to differentiate slots with the same signature